# Module numbers in Webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, webpack

I wonder how'd I identify which `.js` in my project a given number in the built bundle is?

Example:

```
/* [snipped] */

/* 61 */
/***/
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
  "use strict";
  var _typeof3 = __webpack_require__(61);
  var _typeof4 = _interopRequireDefault2(_typeof3);

/* [snipped] */
```

In this example, I see the number 61.  How'd I know which `.js` file in the source folder that this is from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `--display-modules` key to the webpack CLI command

References:

- https://webpack.js.org/

Comment: Many thanks. 1. add `--display-modules` to `webpack` command, 2. look in the `webpack` build output for the number to file mapping.